# Heap block modified past request error in C++

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

I have and QT application with class `Solver` that solve some numeric problem (Bairstow method for finding roots of the polynomial by finding its distribution to trinomials) but while for smaller instances (5 parameters, in array `tabA`) it work fine, but when I tried this for larger instances (7 parameters) application crashed.
After I run the debugger I get the following message:
`Heap block at 02989F58 modified at 02989F80 past request 20`
I'm not exactly sure what is about (well I suppose I get stack overflow but I'm not sure where and how) but it points to line `delete[] Q; delete[] W;` here is how debugger pointed it:
[image]
And here is code of that class methods (the error occurs in main method `int Bairstow(*parameters*)`, which work on class fields and returns number which indicate is solution was found, is not existing or can't be found in given number of iteration)
Here's the main method:

```cpp
int solver::Bairstow(int stopien,double const *tabA, double *tabP,double *tabR, double eps, int N, double p_,double r_)
{
    int i,q, Iter, indpziel=0;
    i=stopien; 

    while(i>=0 && tabA[i]==0) 
    {
        i--;
    } 

    if (i<2) { return 1; } 

    double *A=new double[stopien +1]
    for (i=0;i<=stopien;i++)
    {
        A[i]=tabA[i];
    }
    double *Q=new double[stopien-1 +1];
    double *w=new double[stopien-3 +1];
    double Reszta[2]; 
    double dqdp[2], dqdr[2]; 
    double p,r, a,b,c,d;
    while (stopien>=2) 
    {
        p=p_, r=r_; 
        Iter=O;
        do
        {
            PodzielWiel(stopien,A,p,r,Q,Reszta);
            if (fabs(Reszta[1])<eps && fabs(Reszta[0])<eps)
            {
                break; 
            }
            
            PodzielWiel(Stopien-2,Q,p,r,W,dqdr); 
            for (i=Stopien-2;i>=0;i--)
            {
                Q[i+1]=Q[i];
            }
            Q[0]=0; 
            PodzielWiel(Stopien-1,Q,p,r,W,dqdp); 
            q=LiczMOdwrotna(dqdp[0],dqdr[0],dqdp[1],dqdr[1],a,b,c,d);
            if (q==1) 
            { 
                delete[] Q; 
                delete[] W;
                return 2;
            }
            p = p-(a*Reszta[0]+b*Reszta[1]); 
            r = r-(c*Reszta[0]+d*Reszta[1]); 
        } while (++Iter<N);
        if (Iter==N) return 3; 

        tabP[IndDziel]=p;
        tabR[IndDziel]=r;
        IndDziel++;
        Stopien-=2;
        for (i=0;i<=Stopien;i++)
        {
            A[i]=Q[i];
        } 
    }
    delete[] Q; delete[] W; //that's the line debugger pointed to
    return 0; 
}
```

And two helper methods:

1. for polynomial division (by trinomial x^2-px-r)

```cpp
int solver::PodzielWiel(int stopien,double const *tabA, double p,double r, double *Q,double *R) 
{ 
    if (Stopien<O) return 1; 
    
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=stopien-2;i++)
    { 
        Q[i]=0;
    }

    while (stopien>=0 && tabA[stopien]==0)
    {
        stopien--; 
    }
    if (stopien<2)
    {
        R[0]=tabA[0];
        R[1]=tabA[1]; 
        return 0;
    }

    double *A=new double[Stopien +1]; 
    for (i=0;i<=stopien;i++)
    {
        A[i]=tabA[i];
    }
    Q[stopien-2]=A[stopien];
    if (stopien>2)
    {
        for(i=stopien; i>1; i--)
        {
            Q[i-2]=A[i];
            A[i-1]+=Q[i-2]*p;
            A[i-2]+=Q[i-2]*r; 
        }
        R[1]=A[1];
        R[0]=A[0] ; 
    }
    else
    { 
        R[1]=A[1]+p*Q[0] ;
         R[0]=A[0]+r*Q[0] ; 
    }
    delete [] A; 
    return 0; 
}
```

2. for inversing the 2x2 matrix(first 4 parameters are inputs and next 4 outputs as it):

```cpp
int Solver::LiczMOdwrotna(double x,double y,double w,double z, double &a,double &b,double &c,double &d) 
{ 
    if (x*z==y*w)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (x*w!=0)
    { 
        c=1/(y-z*x/w);
        a=-z*c/w; 
        d=1/(z-y*w/x);
        b=-y*d/x;
    }
    else if (y*z!=0) 
    {
        a=1/(x-w*y/z);
        c=-w*a/z;
        b=1/(w-z*x/y);
        d=-x*b/y; 
    }
    else if (x==0 && z==0)
    { 
        c=1/y;
        d=0; 
        a=0;
        b=1/w;
    }
    else if (y==0 && w==0)
    {
        a=1/x;
        b=0; 
        c=0;
        d=1/z;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

And sory for maybe poor formatting but I have to use OCR software as copying from QT creator was impossible... even after using show in explorer, save file as txt in new localization (to make it visible outside QT Creator) and then doing it again... I still couldn't copy anything...

Comment: Somewhere you're writing outside the bounds of your arrays. Replace all of the `new` uses here with `std::vector`, then a Visual Studio debug build will tell you when you're accessing out of bounds (or replace `z[N]` with `z.at(N)` to get an exception thrown).

Comment: You are calling `Podzielwiel` and `PodzielWiel` but you've only showed the code for `Podzielwiel`. Btw, don't name functions with that similar names.

Comment: I didn't. Actually this was just orc software flaw I didn't noticed where pasting code there. 
And I try this method with std:vector. Though I can't actually do anything with this file outside the QT creator, but maybe it will do anyway. And it actually will be more refactoring than just replace ``new`` with ``std:vector``...

Comment: @Lyokoheros *And it actually will be more refactoring than just replace new with std:vector...* -- Given the code you are showing us, all you have to do is change one line and remove one line.  Change to `std::vector` and remove the call to `delete[]`.  In this day and age of C++, it is considered a big code smell if end-user code uses `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: You mean like changing ``double *Q=new double[stopien-1 +1];`` to ``double *Q=std::vector double[stopien-1 +1];``? (and remove deletions - compiler cleans itself after vectors, right?) Your wording strongly suggest that, but when I try to do this I get error: ``use of class template 'vector' requires template arguments``
So I tried to change it to proper vector declaration I know: ``std::vector<double> Q[stopien-1 +1]``

Comment: But it leads to new problem as function which has ``double const *tabA`` parameter won't accept vector as parameter. And when I try change type in function parameters to std::vector<double> I get ``out of line definition of...``
(Also it's an university project and as far as I remember our teacher ordered us to use this more "traditional" way of dynamic alocation instead of vectors. And I doubt something like "In this day" would convince him...)
So I actually can't make program to work this way and not know how to fix that. Also there is a problem with asigning values while copying tabA to A

Comment: No.  `std::vector<double> Q(stopien-1+1);`  and similar changes to all of those other calls to `new[]`.  Then remove those calls to `delete[]`.  Everything else stays the same.  Now you have a much better chance of solving the problem yourself.  Even if your teacher says to do "A", and you know that doing "B" is easier, try "B" first to make sure your program gives the right results.  Then go back and use "A".  That is what is called "quick prototyping" in the computer world.  Quickly see if the function does its job by using the simplest tools, and in this case, it is `std::vector`.

Comment: *But it leads to new problem as function which has double const *tabA parameter won't accept vector as parameter* -- Then pass `vector.data()` to those functions, as the `data()` member function of vector would return the `double *` pointer to the internal vector buffer.  All a `std::vector` does is *exactly* what your code is trying to do, the only difference is that it does it safer, better, smarter, and with no bugs, all wrapped in a class, with the addition of helper functions.  But behind the scenes, it is using `new` just like your naked raw-array is attempting to do.

Comment: I do this... but well I still don't see where the error actually is. I mean the stack trace seem to point to... inside of vector class itself: [link](https://i.ibb.co/hK0qF3p/Screenshot-2020-10-04-01-39-54.png) - to the fragment when vector is deallocated. Similarly like previous it was pointing to line with ``delete[]``. The line in the class code it point to is last vector declaration (``std::vector<double> W(stopień-3+1);``)
It doeasn't seem like writing outside boundaries to me...